# How to pad a UITableView section header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How would you add some padding to a section header in a UITableView cell?

I have this:
[image]

I have an NSDictionary whose key values contain a string of times. I stored the key values in an NSArray.

I am using titleForHeaderInSection instead of viewForHeaderInSection.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    return [schedule objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

However, the section header is aligned all the way to the left. I can pad it to my liking using a UIView for viewForHeaderInSection, but is there any way to do it for the method titleForHeaderInSection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't easily do it using the titleForHeaderInSection so I decided to use a custom cell  with viewForHeaderInSection.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution is nesting your label in a view. See below for Swift 2 answer:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    // Create the header view
    let headerView =  UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    // Create the Label 
    let label: UILabel? = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 0, 120, 30))
    label!.textAlignment = .Left
    label!.text = "Your Section Title"

    // Add the label to your headerview 
    headerView.addSubview(label)

    return headerView
}
```

And presto, you have a header view with an indentation of 20 on your text :-D

Answer (score 0):

better to use tableView:viewForHeaderInSection

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 30;
}

    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
      UIView *viewHeader = [UIView.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 30)];
      UILabel *lblHeadertitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(YOUR_LEFT_PADDING, YOUR_TOP_PADDING, 200, 20)];
      //customize lblHeadertitle
      lblHeadertitle.text = [schedule objectAtIndex:section];
      [viewHeader addSubview:lblHeadertitle];

      return viewHeader;
    }
```

Comment: But how would I use viewForHeaderInSection to display different section header titles?

Comment: You can set lblHeadertitle.text = [schedule objectAtIndex:section]; see updated answer

Comment: not sure why, but the section titles have disappeared. I tried multiple padding to not avail

Comment: don't forget to set heightForHeaderInSection, see updated answer

Comment: The section header text is off alignment for some reason. No matter what padding I try, it's always in the same wrong location. Please see link: http://s13.postimg.org/jmfqfueiv/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer shown here:
 You have heights `viewHeader` = 30, `lblHeadertitle` = 20.

At the code:

```
UILabel *lblHeadertitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(YOUR_LEFT_PADDING, YOUR_TOP_PADDING, 200, 20)];
```

Set the `YOUR_TOP_PADDING=5` because the `lblHeadertitle` is subview of `viewHeader` and let it be centered in the `viewHeader`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but didn't help, the section header text disappeared completely with your suggestion